# Error synchronizing folder [800CCC0E-0-0-560]. Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

Our iiNet Hosted Exchange is closing, so the email accounts need to be downloaded to Outlook, exported as a .PST file, and imported into a replacement email service.

I received an **Error synchronizing folder [800CCC0E-0-0-560]** when trying to download subfolders into Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Outlook 2016, right-click on the Inbox folder, select IMAP Folders
2. Click the Query button
3. Hopefully you will see the missing folders of Inbox returned from the query to the remote hosted exchange server
4. Now select all Folders in the list, and click Subscribe on the right, then Apply/OK
5. Now go to File > Account Settings > Account Settings
6. Select the email account under the Email tab and click Change
7. In the Root folder path, enter Inbox
8. Click Next, then Done
9. The missing folders should now appear in the folder list of Outlook
10. Click on each folder name to start the download of emails into those folders.

[Source: Error synchronizing folder [800CCC0E-0-0-560]. Inbox subfolders not downloading](https://sdoig.au/blog/tips/microsoft-office-tips/error-synchronizing-folder-800ccc0e-0-0-560-inbox-subfolders-not-downloading/)

Comment: Do you mean you've already sorted it out using the steps above? If so, you can mark your post as best answer for others' referencing.

Comment: Hi @YukiSun, answers can only be accepted 2 days after posting them. `You can accept your own answer in 2 days`

Comment: this fixed me, it drove me nuts for months!   Glad I stumbled-upon this while searching one again.